# Chebychev's Inequality question.... need help?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, chebyshev-polynomials

Please could I have some help with the following question? My initial way of thinking was that Ui must be less than $5$ so that the measurement of the melting point is within $5 $ degrees of $c$, so I set up the inequality

$P(|U - 0n| < 5) ≥ \frac{1}{5^2 391n}$ , where 1/5^2 * 391n is equal to 90%.

However solving this to find n does not give me the integer answer the question asks for, so not sure what to do next.

"You want to determine the melting point 
c
of a new material. You have 
n
specimens on each of which you make a measurement of the melting point in degrees Kelvin, giving you a dataset 
m
1
,…,
m
n
.  We model this with random variables 
M
i
=c+
U
i
, where 
U
i
is the random measurement error. It is known that 
E[
U
i
]=0
and Var
(
U
i
)=391
 for each 
i
, and that we may consider the random variables 
M
1
,
M
2
,…
as independent.
According to Chebyshev's inequality, how many measurements do you need to perform to be 
90%
sure that the average of the measurements is within 
5
degrees of 
c
?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Var\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M_i}{n} \right)=Var\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n U_i}{n} \right)=\frac{Var(U_1)}{n}$$

$$P\left( \left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M_i}{n}-c \right| \ge \frac{k\sqrt{Var(U_1)}}{n}\right) \le \frac1{k^2}$$

If $\epsilon = \frac{k\sqrt{Var(U_1)}}{n}$, then $k = \frac{\epsilon n}{\sqrt{Var(U_1)}}$. Hence ,

$$P\left( \left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M_i}{n}-c \right| \ge \epsilon\right) \le \frac{Var(U_1)}{\epsilon^2n^2}$$

$$P\left( \left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n M_i}{n}-c \right| < \epsilon\right) \ge 1- \frac{Var(U_1)}{\epsilon^2n^2}$$

Hence, we want $$1- \frac{Var(U_1)}{\epsilon^2n^2} \ge 0.9$$

Comment: thank you! so plugging the numbers in would that be 1−
391 / 
5
^2
n
^2

≥0.9

Comment: Seems fine, just solve the inequality.

Comment: hmmm... what do you know about central limit theorem?